# Grep pattern after specific line number in a file

Tags: grep

I am running a while loop in a script ro read a file line by line.

Now I want to run a grep only on the lines below the line I am that is being read by the while loop.

Eg:

If my while loop is on line 4 of the file, the grep only runs below line 4 and does not include line 1,2 and 3.

How is that achievable ?

Regards.

Comment: You should probably build up a list of things *to be searched*, and then run `grep -F <file_with_patterns_one_per_line> <input_file>`.

Comment: So, for every line of the file, you're going to process the entire rest of the file? Pretty inefficient. Please describe the problem you're actually trying to solve and maybe we can offer alternatives.

Comment: wrt `I am running a while loop in a script ro read a file line by line.`. Stop. You are doing it wrong. Post sample input and expected output so we can help you figure out the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with grep alone, but you can if you use its friends:

```
tail +100 file_im_searching | grep pattern_i_want
```

Using the `+` option you can tell tail how far into the file to start.  If you kept track of your line number in the while loop, you could do something like this:

```
tail +$LINENUMBER file | grep pattern
```

Looking at the details of your question, however, I wonder if you'd be better off passing the line that you have through grep or sed or something..

For example, supposing that you have read your line into variable `LINE`, perhaps:

```
set RESULT = $(echo $LINE | grep stuff_to_search_for)
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like what you are asking for:

```
awk 'NR>3 && /regexp/' file
```

but every time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach so if that's what you are doing then post sample input/output if you'd like to see the right way to do it.